# Handlebarsjs "smart" escape

Tags: javascript, escaping, handlebars.js, xss

Is there is any way to setup some sort of settings for handlebars escape so it omit particular tags?
Or if there is any set of helpers that can do this?

e.g. if I allow links in templates it will do following.

> InputSting = "some <\a href='http://link'>out</a> <\script>alert('THERE')</script>"

Template

> {{InputString}}

Compiles to something like:

> some [out](http://link) <\script>alert('THERE')</script>

Disregard backslashes, used to preserve tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a try with this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/ChristopheThiry/m4fgsxof/

First in InputString you need to escape  a bit differently otherwise the javascript will detect you script tag and close the tag in the wrong place :

```
\<script>alert('THERE')\<\/script>
```

Second you can use a helper to cast Handlebars.SafeString on your input string

In your template :

```
{{#link InputString}}
{{/link}}
```

And helper declaration :

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('link', function(text) {
  return new Handlebars.SafeString(text);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Christophe, while the first solution is not viable, as I doubt that someone who will try XSS is going care about escaping. But the second advice put me in [rereading docs](http://handlebarsjs.com/#html-escaping) which has example with very close implementation of what I need.